# Чат с обновлением сообщений

Tags: javascript, php

В общем я совсем запутался...
Пытаюсь сделать чат так, чтобы сообщения в нём обновлялись как только в таблице MySQL появляется новая строчка... 
Сначала хотел сделать при помощи `long polling`, но при активном чате и больших сетевых задержках ("большой ping"), задержки уже более ощутимы. [Длинные опросы (long poll)](http://javascript.ru/ajax/comet/long-poll)

Что лучше использовать?

Потом хотел на `Server-Sent Events`, но для них нужен свой сервер вроде как и я в принципе там ничего не понял... 
[Создание приложений реального времени с помощью Server-Sent Events](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120429/)

Оставалось только одно `WebSockets` но и тут я опять ничегошеньки не понял ...
[Создание приложений реального времени с помощью Server-Sent Events](http://habrahabr.ru/post/79038/)

Вообщем есть код есть:

```
<div id="messeges">

</div>
```

В нем должны обновляться сообщения.

В MySQL таблица `chat`

```
`user_id` `text`
```

Какой должен быть код на обновление?

Comment: Ооо, да вы уже почти весь код написали, остальное вам, конечно же, напишут.  
Нет, вы серьезно? В одном задержки, второе не поняли, третье тоже - вот вам мой ``div#messages``. 
С этим на фриланс. Тут люди задают вопросы.

Comment: //bash
Irishka:
ну я тебе, конечно, чем смогу - тем помогу
но весь диплом за тебя писать не буду

dynamic_by:
ну, это само собой 

dynamic_by:
титульник я сам сделаю

//bash

Comment: Да чёрт с кодом!! Я и не особо рассчитывал на то, что напишет кто нибудь ... Мне хоть скажите конкретно в чём копается... Не три ж технологии сразу изучать!!!

Comment: Можно в гугле поискать "простой чат на php", но это сложная технология поиска, её нужно сначала изучить

Comment: embarcadero с такими замашками тебе сюда http://www.liveexpert.ru/ ..
Да и толку ?! На PHP я и сам напишу а вот как обновлять в реальном времени сообщения я не знаю ..

Comment: Websockets - проблема с поддержкой в браузерах и на WEB сервере.

Comment: Кхм, накатал примерчик, думал уместить как, да походу всё-таки придется запилить в свой бложик. long poll + crossdomain (jsonp). Кроссдомаин пришлось использовать в силу того, что пока один запрос не обработан, второй да этом же домене не пройдет.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте первый способ и нормальный хостинг. Задержка 20-50мс заметна не будет, поверьте. Вы читаете дольше.

Answer (score 0):

Ну это не так уж и сложно.
Javascript

```
(function(){
    ///Здесь функция которая делает ajax запрос к серверу и вставляет в ваш див ответ от сервера, а так же вызывает себя допутим раз в полсекунды 
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 500);
});
```

php

```
<?
  /*
     Здесь запрос к БД и формирование html.  
  */
?>
```

Дальше если голова и руки есть, то все просто, инфы в интернете полно, если есть уже чат без автоматического обновления, то к нему остается прикурить пару строк кода, да и к тому же готовых решений в интернетах полно.

Comment: Сервер вас очень сильно отблагодарит..

Comment: а что не нравится? самый простой метод и работающий.
как минимум для начала самое то, если ТС поймет как это работает, то сможет и чтото посерьезнее использовать если надо будет...

Comment: Раз в полсекунды вполне нормально, если конечно же это не личка в phpbb и тому подобных скриптах, к тому же если это не запускать без надобности, то ерунда это все. Я делал раз в секунду, но там было 5 запросов к БД и работа с большими массивами в php, а это в нем одно из медленных мест, сервер начал падать только при 800-1000 онлайн, приглашенных для накрутки счетчика (с учетом времени в онлайне 10 минут), после чего сделал раз в 10 сек и тишина. А такие как автор вопроса обычно имеют мелкие сайты, так что им это не грозит.

Comment: я так понял что у вас  setTimeout(arguments.callee, 500); пере запускает функцию ?!

А изначально её должно что нибудь запускать ?

Comment: @Kirpich643 запуск ajax запроса и последующий вывод на страницу, все гуглится